# Escape Sequence for Backslash not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say we want our final output to say roll tide:

```
alabama = "roll\ tide"
```

This doesn't work because we need to escape the literal:

```
>>>print(laura.strip('\')

File "<stdin>", line 1
print(laura.strip('\')
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

So I do, using ['\\' as instructed](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), but it still does this:

```
>>>print(laura.strip('\\'))    
roll\ tide
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace it instead:

```
print(alabama.replace('\\',''))
```

Answer (score 2):

i think u need split:

```
>>> alabama.split("\\")
['roll', ' tide']
>>> "".join(alabama.split("\\"))
'roll tide'
```

`strip` only remove from front or end of string

if '\' at was end:

```
>>> alabama = "roll tide\\"
>>> alabama.strip("\\")
'roll tide'
```

you can also use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\\","",alabama)
'roll tide'
```

you can also use `str.replace`:

```
>>> alabama.replace("\\","")
'roll tide'
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip` only works at the beginning and ends of strings.

```
alabama = "\\roll\\ tide\\"
alamaba.strip("\\") # "roll\\ tide"
```

Instead use `str.replace` and replace it with nothing.

```
alabama = "roll\\ tide"
alabama.replace("\\", "") # "roll tide"
```